# Is there a pythonic way to control the flow depending on kwargs in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, keyword-argument, control-flow

i have **register_users** list that have list of user objects and every user object have **password, username, email** property i want to create a **login function** that get a ****kwargs** from input.

the **kwargs** input can be given to the function in 3 different ways.

1. kwargs may have 3 keys **username, password and email**.
2. kwargs may have 2 keys **username or password**.
3. kwargs may have **email or password**.

in all the above we must check whether there is a user object in the **register_user** list whose information is the same as the given input or not.

And the question I have is What is the best way to determine how kwargs input is given?and how to do this with minimum use of **if, ifelse**?or a pythonic way to do this.

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, username, password, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password


user1 = User("user1", "user1@test.com", "test12345")
user2 = User("user2", "user2@test.com", "test12345")

register_users = [user1, user2]

def login(**kwargs):
    pass # determine how kwargs is given to function and then check informations

login({"username": "user1", "email": "user1@test.com", "password": "test12345"})
login({"username": "user1", "password": "test12345"})
login({"email": "user1@test.com", "password": "test12345"})
```

Comment: There are three conditions, so use three if / elseif checks. Three is the minimum and a reasonable one.

Comment: One loop and one if should be enough

Comment: please if you could send your answer code thanks for your help @Imago

Comment: What should happen if there is more than one user that matches? Also, where exactly are you stuck? What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem - how would you do it with pencil and paper? "please if you could send your answer code thanks for your help" Stack Overflow does not work this way. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**, and questions are **not there** in order to solve your problem, but to help build a library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Logically, you always need the password, and either the username or email.
A pythonic way is to retrieve these fields from `kwargs` and take advantage of this to validate the input parameter. From there you can use `getattr` to retrieve either the username either the email from the user.

```py
def login(**kwargs):
     try:
         password = kwargs["password"]
         if "email" in kwargs:
             auth_field, auth_value = "email", kwargs["email"]
         else:
             auth_field, auth_value = "username", kwargs["username"]

     except KeyError:
         raise ValueError("Login requires password and either username or email")

     found_user = None
     for user in registered_users:
         if user.password == password and getattr(user, auth_field) == auth_value:
             found_user = user
             break
```

I assume that this is just for Stackoverflow, but in a real system you probably won't want to store your users in a list, and actual password checking will be slightly more complicated

---

**EDITED** to answer question in comment
if we want to check either one of username/email, either both if they are both present

```
def login(**kwargs):
     try:
         password = kwargs["password"]
         auth_fields = {}
         if "email" in kwargs:
             auth_fields["email"] = kwargs["email"]
         if "username" in kwargs:
             auth_fields["username"] = kwargs["username"]

     except KeyError:
         raise ValueError("Login requires password and either username or email")

     found_user = None
     for user in registered_users:
         if user.password == password and all([getattr(user, field) == value for field, value in auth_fields.items()):
             found_user = user
             break
```

Comment: thanks your answer is perfect its just a question in programing contest sites.i have another question if we have email and username and password at same time in kwargs how should we change our code so that there is no repetition in it? users may have same email or usename we must check both if kwargs contain both of them and in this situation before for loop we must check have email and username or have one of them and It seems to cause repetition in the code @totor

Comment: See updated answer, please accept the answer if it answers your question